# Finding Pukei-Pukei

Tags: monster-hunter-world

I got the 3rd and 4th quests marked as finished through a doing an expedition, so I think I missed some explanation and now I'm stuck on the "Urgent: Pukei-Pukei Hunt" quest.

I was trying to repeat what I did before, which was run around, looking for monster tracks, but I still haven't found a single one for Pukei-Pukei after 3 attempts.

Am I supposed to make some sort of bait?

Answer (score 4):

You are on the right track. Following tracks and clues *is* the way to find new monsters. Pukei-Pukei being no different.

Without directly giving you his initial location (because to me that spoils the fun). The Ancient Forest is a very large map, but Pukei likes the lower, more damp portions of the map. You can find your first trail once you head inwards into the jungle and swampy areas.

If you are absolutely frustrated and just want to know exactly where this guy is...

> Area 6, the northeast most corner of the ancient forest, with the poison flowers.